# Constexpr Variadic Template to reorder unsigned integers

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, c++20

I'm working with a peripheral which sends lowest 8 bit word first. So the first word (in this case 16bit are send) has to be on the right hand side. As seen in variable `v1`.

I would like to have a more expressive version of this so I wanted to add a constexpr function that shifts the first parameter on the right most position of the resulting integer. While still using it as the first parameter of the function.

I didn't really came up with a good solution. As I build up a "shift value" and decrease it upon leaving the recursion. Also, this is not working in a `constexpr` environment, which is for me a "no go". Maybe someone of you has a suggestion ?

I did try a lot of things. But mostly not working. fold expressions also didn't really help.
Cpp Version doesn't matter (c++2a is also okay)

```cpp
// send 0x05 first then 0xFF
std::uint16_t v1 = (0xFFU << 8U | 0x05U); // right align first 8bit word so it is send first
std::uint16_t v2 = lower_word_first(0x05U, 0xFFU); 

// lower_word_first

static std::size_t shift = 0;

auto lower_word_first(){
    return 0;
}

template<typename unsigned_word_type, typename... words>
auto lower_word_first(unsigned_word_type word, words... ws){
    shift += 1;
    auto val = lower_word_first(ws...); // just for debugging purposes split into val
    auto res = val | word << (shift - 1) * 8U;
    shift -= 1;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Provide more examples; are all arguments eventually encoded in a single unsigned type? How long is that type?

Comment: it depends. I did leave out `static_asserts`.
But you will always have an unsigned type which is split in smaller unsigned types.

For example:
uint16_t and the parameters will be two uint8_t.
uint32_t you'll need to pass four uint8_t as parameters.

The reason is that the peripheral will always send data in 1B packets. with the lowest Byte first. So you would need to specify the communication in reverse order (as seen in v1). And with the function I want to create the bigger type in reverse order.

Comment: so v1 and v2 should both give the same result. But with v2 (the variadic template function) you can specify the order of values as they are send out. (So the function needs to reverse them)

Comment: Hope that made it more clear @PiotrSkotnicki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t... Is, typename... Ws>
constexpr auto lower_word_first(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ws... ws)
{
    return ((ws << Is*8) | ...);
}

template <typename... Ws>
constexpr auto lower_word_first(Ws... ws)
{
    return lower_word_first(std::index_sequence_for<Ws...>{}, ws...);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15ca018c0f88f5b5)

Here, [`std::index_sequence_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), e.g.

```
std::index_sequence_for<A, B, C, D>
```

produces:

```
std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3>
```

Then the fold-expression becomes:

```
(ws_0 << 0*8) | (ws_1 << 1*8) | (ws_2 << 2*8) | (ws_3 << 3*8)
```

---

Alternatively, store the arguments in an array, and iterate in reversed direction.

With some [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) features, and a helper function to force a specific type, this can look like:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
auto type()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::uint8_t>) return std::uint16_t{};
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::uint16_t>) return std::uint32_t{};
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::uint32_t>) return std::uint64_t{};
}

template <std::integral W>
constexpr auto lower_word_first(W w, std::same_as<W> auto... ws)
{
    decltype(type<W>()) val{};
    const std::array a = { w, ws... };
    for (auto v : std::ranges::reverse_view{ a }) {
        val <<= 8;
        val |= v;
    }
    return val;
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bDk5jEvdwFMPDcjr)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I intended to do.
Not I just need to understand it :)

Comment: @Nextar Added some hints. It could probably be solved without the extra level of indirection, but it's less readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've learned a few more language aspects thanks to your example :)

Comment: Is there a further reason for the `decltype(type<W>()) val{};` instead of just using `W val{};` As this seems unintuitive for me ?

Comment: @Nextar My understanding of your goal is that arguments of type `uint8_t` should result in `uint16_t`, and that's what `type<W>()` does.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that the `type()` function did return the doubled size. I think this could be further depending on the size of Ws. But thats another story.

Thanks :)